# UITableViewCell is not in the right order after creating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, nsindexpath

I have to create an `UITableView` that contains 2 custom cells **`RestTime`** and **`ExerciseTime`**. That after an **`ExerciseTime`** is a **`RestTime`** cell.
Here is the design of my tableView:

[image: Design TableView]

And here is my implement code:

-Cell's height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // RestTime
        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
            return 40.0f;
        }

        // ExerciseTime
        else {
            return 65.0f;
        }
    }
```

-Number of Cells

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return (self.preset.blocks.count * 2) - 1;
    }
```

-Cell for row

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                {

                    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
                    RestTimeTableViewCell *restTimeCell = (RestTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RestTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    RestTime *restTime = (RestTime *)[self.restTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    //CustomCell
                    return restTimeCell;
                }else{
                    ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *exerciseTimecell = (ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExerciseTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];

                    //Cell index
                    int index = (int)(indexPath.row / 2);
                    //exerciseTimes is a NSSet
                    ExerciseTime *exerciseTime = [self.preset.exerciseTimes.allObjects objectAtIndex:index];

                    //CustomCell
                    return exerciseTimecell;
                }
                return nil;
 }
```

And the output is this :

[image: Output TableView]

I have tried to covert my NSSet to NSMutableArray and its still now working.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                    {

                        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
                        RestTimeTableViewCell *restTimeCell = (RestTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RestTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
                        RestTime *restTime = (RestTime *)[self.restTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                        //CustomCell
                        return restTimeCell;
                    }else{
                        ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *exerciseTimecell = (ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExerciseTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];


                        NSMutableArray *array = [[self.preset.exerciseTimes allObjects] mutableCopy];
                        int index = (int)(indexPath.row / 2);
                        ExerciseTime *exerciseTime = [array objectAtIndex:index];

                        //CustomCell
                        return exerciseTimecell;
                    }
                    return nil;
     }
```

As you can see that all the **`ExerciseCell`** is not in the right order. I cant figure out why it isn't in the right index after the cell is created. I want the order is sorted by the time its created not alphabet abcdef... or 123456... . Can anyone help me to find out what is the problem and how to tackle it.

Comment: @Vinodh Yes i follow that instruction and it has this problem

Comment: `allObjects` doesn't guaranty the order. I don't know if `blocks` is a `NSSet` or else but you may want to check the logic on that. From the doc: `The order of the objects in the array is undefined.`

Comment: @Larme it is a NSSet

Comment: @Vinodh i know but his tableView is different from mine

Comment: @Vinodh it is a NSSet

Comment: @Vinodh can you show everybody and me how to do that because Im still new with this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the problem and it was the NSSet is not sorted at the beginning and I sorted it with @"createdTime" and my problem was solved.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdTime" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.exerciseTimes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

Exercise *exerciseTime = (Exercise *)[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my working Code and screenshot

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *messageTableView;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *datasourceArray;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.messageTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"RestTimeTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RestTime"];
    [self.messageTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ExerciseTimeTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ExerciseTime"];

    self.messageTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.messageTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    self.datasourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        [self.datasourceArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d",i,i,i,i]];
    }


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.datasourceArray.count * 2;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        // RestTime
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        return 40.0f;
    }
        // ExerciseTime
    else {
        return 65.0f;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        RestTimeTableViewCell *restTimeCell = (RestTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RestTime"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //Access you object from array like this

        return restTimeCell;
    }
    else {
        ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *exerciseTimecell = (ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExerciseTime"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //Access you object from array like this
        int index = (int)(indexPath.row / 2);

        exerciseTimecell.exerciseName.text = [self.datasourceArray objectAtIndex:index];
        return exerciseTimecell;
    }
}
@end
```

***Screenshot***

[image]

Comment: I want the order is sorted by the time its created not alphabet abcdef... or 123456...

Comment: It was really nice of you to spend time to solve my problem however since i wasn't describe my problem good enough for you to understand or led you to misunderstand . I had found out my issue was because the NSSet just as you suggested, I converted it in NSMutableArray and sorted it with key @"createdTime" and my problem was solved. Thank you for your time and your concern.

Comment: no issues man . Post it as a answer so other will know how to fix it

Comment: Yes of course. I have posted it if you wanna check that.

Answer (score 0):

`NSSet` just be a set, there's no order between objects. If you'd like to keep the order, you can use `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) instead of `NSSet`.

Comment: try using self.preset.exerciseTimes[index] instead of allObjects[index].

Comment: @VMCuongOnStackOverflow: For more information: There're 3 regular kinds of set in ObjC. **The first** is `NSSet`, it just be a simple set, so there no order between objects (random order). **The second** is `NSArray/ NSMutableArray`, it's an ordered set, retrieve an object via its index. **The third** is `NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary`, it's an set without ordered, retrieve an object via key.